# Where is the header that defines the `publisher(for:)` method that yields a KeyValueObservingPublisher?

Tags: ios, combine

I can see the Foundation header that defines `NSObject.KeyValueObservingPublisher`. But I can't find the header that defines the `publish(for:)` method that returns this publisher. And I can’t find it in the documentation.

It must involve NSObject, because only an NSObject can be observed with KVO. And it must come in the forms `publisher(for:)` and `publisher(for:options:)`, because that's what code completion offers me in Xcode. But *where* is code completion getting that information *from?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not in the documentation and it’s not visible in Xcode when you jump to the headers. I found it, however, hidden in a *.swiftinterface* file inside Xcode:

```
@available(OSX 10.15, iOS 13.0, tvOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, *)
extension _KeyValueCodingAndObservingPublishing where Self : ObjectiveC.NSObject {
    public func publisher<Value>(for keyPath: Swift.KeyPath<Self, Value>, options: Foundation.NSKeyValueObservingOptions = [.initial, .new]) -> ObjectiveC.NSObject.KeyValueObservingPublisher<Self, Value>
}
```

So the declaration exists but it’s undocumented.

I think the problem here is that this method is declared in an extension to a protocol `_KeyValueCodingAndObservingPublishing` that is made invisible to the documentation and the generated interface by the underscore. I regard that as a bug.

**EDIT:** Rob Mayoff points out in a comment that you can also look in the source code at https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/main/Darwin/Foundation-swiftoverlay/Publishers%2BKeyValueObserving.swift.

Comment: Anyone who wants to look at the `.swiftinterface` file can find it at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/swift/Foundation.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftinterface`.

Comment: @robmayoff Yes, that's what my answer says. But "anyone" is disingenuous; finding stuff that way is not simple. My point is that if there is something to be known, the generated interface and documentation should let us know it.

Comment: I agree that `publisher(for:options:)` needs to be in the documentation. But I think it's useful to provide the path to the file for those interested in exploring what else is in that file (and other nearby files).

Comment: @robmayoff I haven't worked out any general rule for predicting where something will be. I mostly just do a global search. I suppose _Foundation.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftinterface_ was fairly predictable... :)

Comment: I just found out that Foundation's Combine adapters are part of the Swift repository. Here's [Publishers+KeyValueObserving.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e162d0a2bacb39d2dff1a9bd8e6289e8f6467d95/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/Publishers%2BKeyValueObserving.swift).