# How to develop AVPlayerItem observers using Combine

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, combine, avplayeritem

I want to develop AVPlayerItem observers using combine. I found a [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60646857/swiftui-combine-for-onreceive-notifications-with-avplayer) code using **PassthroughSubject** but this is not what I'm looking for I want more generic way of doing it.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What do you mean by: ` I want more generic way of doing it.`?

Comment: Hi thanks, there are multiple values that we can observe right, so I want to write code using generics so that I don't have to repeat the code for every observers. I even want to split into multiple classes if possible instead of keeping everything in one class